# How to ask for the date of the homework?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

How should a student ask their teacher for the due date of the homework? Should they ask:

> **A:** "When is the homework due?”
>   **B:** “What date is the homework due?”
>   **C:** “What's the date for the homework?”
>   **D:** “When is the homework for?”

Are these correct and pertinent? Are there any other ways to put it?

Comment: Options A and B are fine. Option C is acceptable, but not as good as the first two. Avoid Option D.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest correct way would be.

> A: When is the homework due?

In context, "When's it due?" also works.

You could also use B, but it is no improvement on A.

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely agree that B has "no improvement." In my mind, anyway, Option A could be answered with a date or a time, particularly for an on-line class. Option B makes it clear we are more interested in the date than the time of day.

Comment: I feel that the context (asking about homework) already makes it sufficiently clear that we are asking about days or dates, and not about hours or minutes.

Comment: I can tell you've never taught an online class. :-)  A due date usually suffices when students hand in their assignments at the beginning or end of class time. Online classes, though, often have homework due at various odd hours.